# Nilpotent problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, nilpotence

Ok so I am stuck with this ring problem in past paper problems, and it goes:

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity $1$. Prove that if $J$ is defined by $J=\{{1-b|b\in R 
 \text{  nilpotent}\}}$, then it is a group under multiplication. Also suppose $R$ is finite with $n=|R|$, and $b$ nilpotent then prove that $(1-b)^n=1$.

I would appreciate the help, as I'm stuck with ring concepts at the moment, doing alot of problems with examples will really help me understand things better.

Comment: I assume you know what a group is. What's stopping you from checking that the properties of a group is satisfied by $(J, \cdot)$?

Comment: @Arthur Well technically the group part I found the inverse , but to show ab is closed, I did $(1-a)(1-b)=(1-(a+b)+ab)$, but how do I show that $(a+b)-ab$ is infact nilpotent is the part I am actually stuck at. And also I have no idea about the $(1-b)^n=1$ part.

I might have an idea of the last part, is it enough to show that the order of $J$ divides the order of $R$, then we are done? But how do we show order of $J$ is the divisor of order of $R$?

Comment: (Finite) sums and products of nilpotent elements are nilpotent. If $a^m= 0$ and $b^n = 0$, then concider $(a+b)^{m+n}$ and $(ab)^{\min(m, n)}$. From there, we get that $a+b-ab$ is nilpotent without too much work.

Comment: By the way, I really like your title. “Nilpotent problems” – sounds like if you just let them multiply enough, they vanish by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hints*. Use the binomial formula to show that the set all of nilpotents $\operatorname{nil} R = \{x ∈ R;~\text{$x$ is nilpotent}\}$ is an additive subgroup of $R$. For the other part, use Lagrange’s theorem to show that $\lvert J \rvert$ divides $\lvert R \rvert$ by noting that $J$ is a coset of $\operatorname{nil} R$.

---

Namely, $J = 1 + \operatorname{nil} R$. Therefore $\operatorname{nil} R → J,~x ↦ 1 + x$ is a well-defined bijection. So $\lvert J \rvert = \lvert \operatorname{nil} R \rvert$.

Comment: Do I have to show that $J$ is a subring of the ring $R$? Then we can directly use Lagrange's theorem to prove $(1-b)^n=1?$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis It suffices to show that it is an additive subring. It’s not a subring if you define a ring to be unitary. Instead, it’s an *ideal* (the *nilradical* $\operatorname{nil} A$). (An ideal $I ⊆ A$ is an additive subgroup closed under “scalar multiplication” of $R$, that is a $R$-submodule of $R$, in case you didn’t know.)

Comment: I am quite confused to why this is so. I think I am getting further away from understanding how to solve this problem. Because from what I understand, if order of $|J|$ is a divisor of $|R|$ then immediately $(1-b)^n =1$ follows, but its this part of trying to get $|J|$ to divide I am having a hard time understanding. For instance $R$ is a ring, and $J$ is a coset of $\text{nil} A$ like you mentioned, I dont understand how $|J|$ can divide $|R|$ if $J$ is not a subring of $R$?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis First of all: Uh, sorry! I made a mistake. I thought you meant the nilradical by $J$, so $J$ is *not* an additive subgroup of $R$, but merely a multiplicative set. I meant that $\operatorname{nil} A$ is an additive subgroup.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Next, I just updated my answer to flesh out the argument. Maybe things are clearer now?

Comment: Ok thank you for the correction, so it seems like since $\text{nil}A $ is a subring of the commutative ring $R$, then it implies that the $|\text{nil}A| $divides $|R|$ by Lagrange's theorem, and since $|\text{nil}A| = |J|$, $|J|$ divides $|R|. |J|$ implies $(1-b)^m =1$, for some $|J|=m$, so since $n\ge m$, $(1-b)^n=1$?

Comment: First, as mentioned before, $\operatorname{nil} A$ is *no* subring if you require that rings have a unit. It is an *additive subgroup* of $R$ (and even an *ideal* in $R$), which suffices for our case: It implies that $\lvert \operatorname{nil} A \rvert$ divides $n = \lvert R \rvert$, hence $\lvert J \rvert$ divides $n$. Next, $J$ is a *multiplicative subgroup* of $(R,·,1)$. So for all $x ∈ J$, $x^n = 1$ by Lagrange, as $n$ is a multiple of $\lvert J \rvert$.

Comment: Thank you I now understand more than when I asked this question. Just one more question, why cant $\text{nil}A$ be a subring if a ring has a unit?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis If you require rings to have a unit, you better require a subring – being a ring itself – to have a unit, too. But if $1 ≠ 0$, then $1^n = 1 ≠ 0$ for all $n$, so $\operatorname{nil} R$ is a subring of $R$ if and only if $R = 0$. More generally, an ideal $I ⊆ R$ is a subring of $R$ if and only if $I = R$. (By the way, I just realised that I used $A$ as a letter for the ring instead of $R$ when talking about the nilradical out of habit. So replace all $A$s by $R$s.)